# CGImageRef from NSData is null, but UIImage is not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage, cgimageref

I'm trying to move some image loading into the background. Currently i'm loading UIImages in the background but from what I have read, this is not the suggested way to go about doing it, instead I should load the CGImageRef in the background, then load the UIImage from it in the main thread.

The problem is that when I try to create a `CGImageRef`, its coming back as null. Sample code:

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: coverPath];
if(nil != imageData)
{
    UIImage * uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef) imageData);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    NSLog(@"Test: %p, %p", imageRef, uiImage);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
}
```

Which logs out `Test: 0x0, 0x1c566bb0`. Meaning the imageRef is null but the uiImage is not. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here? It seems as if this should be quite simple?

Comment: Just a side note from [What's New in iOS 4.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html)
`Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically: The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads. String and image drawing is now thread-safe. Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.` If drawing is thread-safe you can use UIImage directly in the background for (just) loading.

Comment: This is an even better answer than trying to figure out why I can't get the imageRef working! Although I will keep the answer open, as I would still like to know the solution :)

Comment: Did you ever check to see if `provider` was maybe coming back nil?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that, the `provider` is NOT null.

Comment: And the file really contains PNG data and not JPEG or TIFF?

Comment: Ugh. Even though the files I was provided with had the .png extension, they were indeed not pngs. I opened them in preview, exported as new png files and tried with those files. Everything worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider()
```

returns `nil` if the provided data is not in PNG format (for example JPEG or TIFF).

```
[UIImage imageWithData: imageData]
```

returns an image for all supported image file formats (PNG, JPEG, TIFF etc.)

This explains why the first function can fail while the second succeeds.